# Como podría mostrar un pedido por ID y no mostrar todos los pedidos en cada ID?

Tags: php, mysqli

LLevo horas con este problema, agradezco de antemano por sus ayudas. Así se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Evidentemente necesito que se muestre tipo 13190 - Advanced Night Repair Eye - 10 kg. x 5 debajo 13189 - Advanced Night Repair Eye - 10 kg. x 1 y así sucesivamente...

```
    <?php
      // Conexión a la base de datos
      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $password = "";
      $dbname = "shopusaec_sys";

      // Crear conexión
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

      // Verificar la conexión
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Error de conexión: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }
      // Consulta para obtener los datos de la tabla cajas_pedidos_data
      $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, estado, pedidos, nombre_producto, peso_total, ultima_actualizacion 
      FROM cajas_pedidos_data
      ORDER BY id DESC"; // DESC ordena de mayor a menor
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // Mostrar los datos en una tabla
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          // Obtener los ids de los pedidos
          $pedido_ids = explode(",", $row["pedidos"]);
          // Mostrar los datos de la caja en la tabla

         // Establecer el background-color dependiendo del estado
  if ($row["estado"] == "Pendiente") {
    $bg_color = "#f72d2d";
  } elseif ($row["estado"] == "En tránsito") {
    $bg_color = "#0174cf";
  } elseif ($row["estado"] == "Entregado") {
    $bg_color = "#2db510";
  } elseif ($row["estado"] == "En proceso") {
    $bg_color = "#ff8800";
  } else {
    $bg_color = "";
  }

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row["id"]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row["nombre"]."</td>";
  
  echo "<td style='color:white;font-weight:700;background-color: $bg_color !important;'>".$row["estado"]."</td>";

        
          echo "<td>";
          foreach ($pedido_ids as $pedido_id) {
            
            echo "<style>.ped{color:black;padding:5px;border-radius:5px;text-decoration:none;}</style><a class='ped' href='ver-pedido.php?id=".$pedido_id."'>".$pedido_id." - ".$row["nombre_producto"]."</a> <br><br> ";
          }
          echo "</td>";          
          
          echo "<td>".$row["peso_total"]." kg"."</td>";
          echo "<td>".count($pedido_ids)."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row["ultima_actualizacion"]."</td>";
          echo "<td>";
          echo "<a href='editar_caja.php?id=".$row["id"]."' class='btn btn-primary'>Editar</a> ";
          echo "<a href='borrar_caja.php?id=".$row["id"]."' class='btn btn-danger'>Borrar</a
          '>";
          echo "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
      } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='8'>No se encontraron cajas</td></tr>";
      }
      $conn->close();
      ?>
```

COMO NECESITO QUE SE VEA:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso sería todo, agradezco sus respuestas. Por cierto estuve probando con CHATGPT me dice Aquí estamos ejecutando una consulta SQL adicional dentro del bucle foreach para obtener el nombre del producto correspondiente a cada pedido individual. Luego, usamos ese nombre de producto en lugar del nombre de producto correspondiente a la caja completa en la línea donde se muestra el nombre del producto. Con esta corrección, la tabla mostrará correctamente el nombre del producto correspondiente a cada pedido individual. Pero no entiendo como podría implementarlo

Comment: No entiendo bien el problema, como debería ser la salida esperada ??

Comment: He agregado una segunda imagen con el resultado que necesito que aparezca, gracias Yussef

Comment: algo me dice que lo que esta mal es tu base de datos y tu query, si necesitas hacer un for dentro del while...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas guardando en un celda, multiples valores separados por `,`. Recomendaria usar otro método, un JSON o de plano colocar esos datos en otra tabla. Y en último caso, cambiar el separador de `,` a un carácter más raro un `|` o `#`, ya que si un nombre incluye la coma como parte de su nombre (que es posible) te va funcionar como el or.. muy mal

Sobre tu problema:

Haces esto:

```
$pedido_ids = explode(",", $row["pedidos"]);
```

Te falta hacer lo mismo con `$row["nombre_producto"]`, algo así:

```
$pedido_nombres = explode(",", $row["nombre_producto"]);
```

Luego el `foreach` lo reemplazamos por un `for`

```
foreach ($i=0; $i< count($pedido_ids); $++;) {
 echo "<a class='ped' href='ver-pedido.php?id=".$pedido_ids[$i]."'>".$pedido_ids[$i]." - ".$pedido_nombres[$i]."</a> <br><br> ";
}
```

Además tienes un

```
<style>.ped{color:black;padding:5px;border-radius:5px;text-decoration:none;}</style>
```

Que lo estas repitiendo en cada fila, esto no es necesario. Colócalo en tu archivo CSS, o en último caso arriba de todo (antes del `while`)